# Is it possible to provide a wired ethernet connection to external devices with an extra LAN card?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, home-networking, lan

I'm trying to provide a wired ethernet connection (wireless is not an option for this device) to a device ([Samsung blu-ray player](http://www.samsung.com/us/consumer/tv-video/blu-ray/blu-ray-players/BD-P1590/XAA/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=features)) without running Cat5 cable all over the home.  I have a PC sitting next to this device and the PC is connected to the network via a wireless USB adapter.

**Is it possible to provide a wired connection** ***from*** **the PC to the wired device using the (currently unused) ethernet port in the back of the computer?**

Here's how I envision the device getting connected to the internet via my network:

```
Linksys WRT54G v8 Wireless Router
  |
   ``--> Windows 7 PC connected via wireless
         |
          ``--> Blu-ray player connected via wired connection to the 
               ethernet port on the PC.
```

If so, how is this done? Will I need a crossover cable?  What settings will I need to change in Windows 7 so that the device can connect?

*NOTE: I'm trying to avoid having to buy a wireless bridge and/or hacking a router with an open-source firmware to get this to work.  See my [previous question](https://superuser.com/users/16909/ben-mccormack) for more details.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Step by step Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) setup in Vista](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-vista/step-by-step-internet-connection-sharing-ics-setup-in-vista/)**

works pretty much the same way in Windows 7, use 192.168.0.1 (255.255.255.0) for the Windows 7 LAN connection and use 192.168.0.2 (255.255.255.0) with 192.168.0.1 as gateway and DNS server for the bluray player.

Comment: Thanks for the link. On that site, it specifically mentions setting up a **PC** as the client device.  I need to make sure I can configure my blu-ray device accordingly.

Comment: Also, do you know if this requires a crossover cable or will a regular patch cable work?

Comment: regular ethernet cable. as for configuring the device, i'm sure you can specify IP, subnet and gateway, if 192.168.0.1 is your windows 7 machine then use 192.168.0.2 as IP and 192.168.0.1 as gateway/DNS server on the bluray player.

Comment: In this sense, am I setting up my Win7 machine as a router? I have a router already with IP of 192.168.1.1. Should I make the Win7 machine static and use DHCP or static on the device?

Comment: @Ben: sorta.  it's more like a bridge than a router, but it's not exactly that either.  you should leave your Win7 wireless connection alone; whatever it currently uses will continue to work.  the wired connection, and the blueray, well, for 2 connections it's probably easiest just to set them as static addresses.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly. I can do webpage HTML coding, but wires get tangled up...

How do you play the BluRay movie on your Win7 PC player through the multi-line router (has the DSL connection) to the BluRay player's LAN connection that is connected to the TV by HDMI?

It took me forever to find out how to play a .DVI movie on my PC through a 25' HDMI to HDMI connection on my HD TV.  I had to use multi-display mode on my monitor setup and DRAG the movie in the player (in this case DIVX player) to the other monitor...whew...that was an adventure.

Thanks.